# Linearly independent operators on $End(V) \iff (v, T(v), T^2(v),\dots, T^m(v))$ l.i. on $V$?

Tags: linear-algebra

> **Definition.** A finite family $(v_1,\dots ,v_n)$ on a vector space $V$ is said to be linearly independent (l.i.) if
>   $$
> x_1v_1 + x_2v_2 +\cdots + x_mv_m = 0
> $$
>   has only the trivial solution.
>
> **Proposition.** Let $End_{\mathbb{F}}(V)$ be the space of all linear operators over the vector space $V$. Then 
>   $$
> (T^k)_{0\le k\le m} = (Id_V, T, T^2,\dots , T^m) 
> $$
>   is a l.i. family on $End_{\mathbb{F}}(V)$ if, and only if,
>   $$
> (T^k(v))_{0\le k\le m} = (v, T(v), T^2(v),\dots , T^m(v))
> $$
>   is a l.i. family on $V$ for all $v\in V\setminus 0$.

I'm thinking whether this is correct or what changes I must do to make it correct, or whether it's incorrect at all. I sketched a simple proof but it implies that $a_0Id_V(v)+\cdots+a_mT^m(v)$ would be injective so I think the proposition is not correct. Somebody can confirm it or show a counterexample?

Comment: Certainly not for all $v\neq0$: if $\mathbb F$ is algebraically closed and $v$ is an eigenvector of $T$, then $(T^k(v))_k$ has rank $1$ while $(T^k)_k$ does not if $T$ is not scalar. I wonder if it becomes true if we replace "all" by "some".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is indeed incorrect. Suppose $T\ne0$ and $v\ne0$, but $T(v)=0$ (that is, $T\ne0$ is not injective). Then $(\mathrm{Id}_V,T)$ is linearly independent, because $T$ is not a scalar multiple of $\mathrm{Id}_V$, but $(v,T(v))$ is not linearly independent.

An example can be built when $V$ has dimension at least $2$: take a basis $(v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n)$ of $V$ and define $T(v_1)=0$ and $T(v_i)=0$, for $i>1$.